# Round SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

how do I evit avoid rounding in SQL Server

```
DECLARE @NUMERO1 AS numeric(26,8) = 0
DECLARE @NUMERO2 AS numeric(26,8) = 0

SET @NUMERO1 = 1.92306964
SET @NUMERO2 = 105
SELECT 1.92306964 * @NUMERO2
SELECT @NUMERO1* @NUMERO2
```

Is not the same result.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want better precision, use FLOAT rather than NUMERIC/DECIMAL types. Try the following instead:

```
DECLARE @NUMERO1 AS FLOAT = 1.92306964
DECLARE @NUMERO2 AS FLOAT = 105
SELECT 1.92306964 * @NUMERO2 -- 201.9223122
SELECT @NUMERO1 * @NUMERO2  -- 201.9223122
```

Answer (score 0):

When you hard code a number like that in SSMS it gets treated as a float, not numeric, which behaves differently. To make the output of your two select statements match, you would need to write something like this:

```
DECLARE @NUMERO1 AS numeric(26,8) = 0
DECLARE @NUMERO2 AS numeric(26,8) = 0

SET @NUMERO1 = 1.92306964
SET @NUMERO2 = 105
SELECT cast(1.92306964 as numeric(26,8)) * @NUMERO2
SELECT @NUMERO1* @NUMERO2
```

However, I assume you want the greater precision of float that will let you work backwards like such:

```
DECLARE @NUMERO1 AS float = 0
DECLARE @NUMERO2 AS float = 0

SET @NUMERO1 = 1.92306964
SET @NUMERO2 = 105
SELECT 1.92306964 * @NUMERO2
SELECT @NUMERO1 * @NUMERO2 
SELECT (1.92306964 * @NUMERO2) / 1.92306964 -- returns @NUMERO2 as expected
SELECT (@NUMERO1 * @NUMERO2) / @NUMERO1 -- returns @NUMERO2 as expected
```

Comment: Yes, but... what happens whent the number is big, the round for float fail, it converts a number with exponential.

Comment: What do you mean by big? How big do you want to go? `float(38)` will store up to 38 digits (the same as the maximum precision allowed using `decimal`) with the decimal point "floating" anywhere along those digits. E.g. `declare @bignum float(38) = 11112222333344445555.006666777788889999` is valid in SSMS. It will only display 15 digits in the results window, but it will still perform calculations on the entire number. See [float and real](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx) and [decimal and numeric](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) for more details.